# Device selection disabled in Xcode 4, green light in organizer

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4

I'm trying to test an app on a 3G with 4.2.1 installed, but I'm unable to select the device in the scheme in Xcode (4.0.2).  The app is built on the 4.3 SDK, but targeted for deployment to 4.2.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Since the two solutions below didn't work for you then the issue is probably your phone. I assume you have an iOS Developer account and have downloaded the necessary profiles and certificates from the provisioning portal?

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate all the views and suggestions.  Turns out I had the target deployment version of iOS set to 4.3 in the target build settings, and I was working with the project build settings.

Grrr.  I've made this exact same mistake several times.  No matter how experienced I get at this, it's easy to mess this up.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Xcode with the device already connected. I also experience this problem on some installations of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Me too. I have found that editing the active scheme ( cmd-< )and briefly switching the build configuration and then switching back fixes the issue.

Comment: This didn't help for me (unless I'm not doing what you did, exactly).