# Xcode 4.2 not detecting Device(ios6)

Tags: ipad, ios5, xcode4.2, device

I trying to connect my device `iPAD (iOS 6.0)` to the `X-code(4.2 with iOS 5.0)` but device is not been detecting..I have made all the changes..Device can been seen in the `Organizer` but not in the X-code.I have taken Provisional certificate and keychain certificate both are valid. now In Xcode In `Build Identifier` I have edited ,Even Made changes in `Code Signing identity` of the Target and my app .What more changes do it required.

`Base SDK` of the Target Device is 5.0 ,Would it be possible to run from lower to high configuration..

Even I have Tried all the previous post related to this question but does not work for me...

Comment: In organizer is it showing a green dot or yellow dot against the device when it is connected? Any screenshot available?

Comment: it is yellow dot , but provisional certificate is valid one

Comment: Is there a message that `it does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK`? If I am correct Xcode 4.2 wont support devices with OS > iOS 5.0.

Comment: no actually few days it was working fine... and I was testing my app that time my device got hanged (in app) and I restated the device but after that this problem created, device is not been detecting in Xcode..

Comment: Is there any other message displayed? If not, you might have to reinstall your Xcode and check. Also try to restart the device. Make sure the provisional profile is installed in both organizer and device.

Comment: ya I have done all these steps but not working..can you tell where this message would be displayed and when?? bcz I haven't seen any message...

Comment: In the organizer window, when you select the device it should show there in that screen. Check the image in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024566/device-selection-disabled-in-xcode-4-green-light-in-organizer and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632044/xcode-no-provisioned-ios-device-is-connected

Comment: This is wat http://i45.tinypic.com/14in01t.png I am getting

Comment: Added as an answer. Was that iPad OS upgraded recently? The error message in that screenshot is telling that right now it is iOS 6.0.1 and you cant run that in this 4.2 version of Xcode.

Comment: So Larme has already given the correct answer ...

Comment: @MartinR how can i put my app from\ iTunes or iPhone Configuration Utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image you have attached in comments, it is pretty clear that the iPad had been recently upgraded to iOS 6.0.1 and since your version of Xcode is 4.2, it supports only devices with version up to 4.2. You can either restore the device version as mentioned there or install a new Xcode and iOS SDK which supports iOS 6.0.1.

It might have been working earlier when the iPad OS version was iOS 5.0 or below.

For adding using iTunes, check [this](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad7eed) and for iPhone Configuration Utility [check this](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad6ebd) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_iPhone_Configuration_Utility/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: no as i said ...i didn't make any update that hang created this problem..I think now I should restore the iOS

Comment: I am not sure how it worked for you. After that hang, probably the device got updated somehow?

Comment: no i am not sure...and also how can i  put your app into your iOS6 iDevice, is by using iTunes or iPhone Configuration Utility

Comment: For adding using iTunes, check this http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad7eed and for iPhone Configuration Utility check http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad6ebd and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_iPhone_Configuration_Utility/Introduction/Introduction.html. I am not sure these two methods will work since the Xcode is an old version and you have to create ipa file for iOS 6.0. Try it out.

Comment: @Christien, There is a small tick mark next to the answer which you can use to express your gratitude.. :)

Answer (score 2):

*XCode 4.2* does not support *iOS6*.
If you don't want to update your *XCode*, a way to put your app into your iOS6 iDevice, is by using *iTunes* or *iPhone Configuration Utility*

Comment: hey few days back It worked for me..and I want to put app to for testing purpose ..what should i do